# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\|x-v\|dVol_{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, divergence-theorem

> Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\|x-v\|dVol_{n-1}$ for $v\in\mathbb{R}^n,\|v\|<1$ by using the Divergance theorem.

I've thought of taking $F=\frac{x}{\|x\|}\|x-v\|$ but I think it will make the other integral hard aswel to solve and $N(x)=x$ normal to the unit sphere

Comment: You have it backwards. Since this is the boundary integral, you have to take the integrand's divergence, not undo it. Hint: the boundary integrand is secretly a dot product, and the dot product has already been taken.

Comment: @NinadMunshi You are right

Comment: Another hint: $||x||=1$ on $S^{n-1}$ so feel free to include or exclude as many factors of it as you like.

Comment: The problem is there is a simple solution without divergence theorem, but I can't think of one that uses it in an easy to calculate way.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I've tried couple of things but didn't get anything.maybe can you solve this with the divergence thm?

Comment: The easiest solution is without divergence theorem. Take the gradient of that integral w.r.t. $v$. Then you're basically integrating over all the possible unit vectors, which all add up to $0$ (or argue the integral is odd with a clever choice of coordinate system). Since the integral is constant w.r.t. $v$, calculate the integral with $v=0$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Can you write this and I'll accept it as an answer